# yith membership plugin can't remove woocommerce price and add to cart button in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed yith membership plugin on my wordpress website which has ability to remove woocommerce price and add to cart buttons, and it does it only when the price and button are called with woocommerce_single_product_summary hook. ( it does work in wordpress default templates ). But in the template that I bought the price and add to cart button are called directly with these codes :

```
<?php woocommerce_template_single_price(); ?>

<?php woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart(); ?>
```

and somehow the plugin can't identify them.

and also here is the code that I think does the removing job :

```
public function hide_price_and_add_to_cart() {
        $hide_price_and_add_to_cart = 'yes' === yith_wcmbs_settings()->get_option( 'yith-wcmbs-hide-price-and-add-to-cart' );
        if ( $hide_price_and_add_to_cart ) {
            global $product;

            if ( $product ) {
                $downloadable    = yith_wcmbs_is_downloadable_product( $product );
                $base_product_id = yit_get_base_product_id( $product );

                if ( $downloadable && $this->user_has_access_to_product( get_current_user_id(), $base_product_id ) && ( apply_filters( 'yith_wcmb_skip_check_product_needs_credits_to_download', false ) || ! $this->product_needs_credits_to_download( get_current_user_id(), $base_product_id ) ) ) {

                    $hook      = 'woocommerce_single_product_summary';
                    $to_remove = array(
                        'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',
                        'woocommerce_template_single_price',
                    );

                    foreach ( $to_remove as $callback ) {
                        $priority = has_action( $hook, $callback );
                        if ( false !== $priority ) {
                            remove_action( $hook, $callback, $priority );
                        }
                    }

                    do_action( 'yith_wcmbs_hide_price_and_add_to_cart' );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

anyone has any idea about how to make changes to plugin or the template to make this work ?

I tried removing the $hook part from the plugin code but it's not working